# Reflexivity of Relations

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Explain why the relation 
$$T=\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}:a≤b\}$$ 
is reflexive, but the relation
$$ Q=\{(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}:a<b\}$$
is not reflexive.

Is $T$ reflexive because $a$ can equal $b$? While in $Q$, $a$ can only be smaller than $b$ and not equal to be reflexive as in $T$.

Comment: Yeah, you got it.

Answer (score 0):

You've got it precisely right. We know that an equivalence relation $\sim$ on a set $X$ is reflexive if $x \in X$ satisfies $x\sim x$. Is it possible for a real number $x$ to satisfy $x<x?$ No. However, any real number can (and does) satisfy $x\le x$. So, $"\le"$ is a reflexive relation on $\mathbb{R}$, while $"<"$ is not.

Answer (score 0):

If every element in the set is related to itself, then the relation is [Reflexive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_relation).

every $a \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $a \leq a$. So $T=\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}:a≤b\}$ is reflexive.

No real number satisfies $a < a$. So $Q=\{(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}:a<b\}$ is not reflexive.